# JSP java io file last date modified is epoch eventhough in FTP the file date is yesterday- tomcat6

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have read a directory of files. I got all the file list out.. but there is something wrong with the last modified date. I check with ftp application that the date of the file is yesterday.

part of the code is

```
File file1 = new File(filePath+retFilename);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy h:mm:ss a");
long getModifiedDateTime = file1.lastModified();
java.util.Date fmtModifiedDateTime = new java.util.Date(getModifiedDateTime);                   
String getModifiedDate = sdfDate.format(fmtModifiedDateTime);
```

the modified date is alway return epoch. and there is no i/o exception caught.
my ftp application is core FTP

one more thing is

```
long fileSize = file1.length();
```

the file size seems to be 0. does it have anything to do with last modified date?

Comment: Zero file size nothing to do with last modified date. I think FTP is client side software, which uses local timezone.

Comment: even though it uses local time zone, the last modified date should be there right? but all this return the epoch time, which is the 1 jan 1970...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.lastModified` returns `0L` if the file does not exist or if there is some kind of I/O error -- probably including inadequate file permissions. The only time an exception should be thrown is if a `SecurityManager` revokes access to the resource. This is likely to be the reason you see "01-01-1970" (a confusing date format IMO) when you try this.

Try using `File.isFile`, `File.isDirectory`, `File.exists`, or `File.canRead` before attempting to call `File.lastModified`: you may have a `File` object that doesn't point to a valid location.